# Close github repo issue via linked bitbucket repo commit message

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am committing source code to a free private bitbucket repository and using an empty github repository to manage issues.

I value the github workflow ability to close an issue by referencing it in a commit message.

Is is possible to link the bitbucket repo with the github repo so bitbucket commits can close github issues?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you could consider setting up a:

- **[webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-rest-apis/manage-webhooks)** in order to listen to a bitbucket push event
- push a dummy commit to the GitHub repo (with the same commit message from the Bitbucket push event)

That means you need a server able to listen to the webhook JSON payload and react to it.

It is important to push a dummy commit, in order to not leak the content of the bitBucket (*private*) repo content.